# Shared Preferences for a string in Android

Tags: android, string, sharedpreferences, preferences

I am trying to set preference for a string value as:

```
//onCreate
    if(name==null){
                setprefer();
            }
            else{
                getpref();
            }

    private void setprefer() {
            et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    s = et1.getText().toString();
                    if(s.matches(""))
                    {
                        //wait!! 
                        Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        setpref(s);
                        Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, Homescreen.class);
                        i.putExtra("name", s);
                        startActivity(i);
                        Home.this.finish();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void setpref(String name) {
            SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("prefkey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putString("key", name);
            editor.commit();        
        }
        private void getpref() {
            SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("prefkey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            s = prefs.getString("key", name);
            Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, Homescreen.class);
            i.putExtra("name", name);
            startActivity(i);
            Home.this.finish();
        }
```

I am setting the preference with the method setprefer() but each time i start my activity its asks fr the name which i have already stored in my preference.
Somehow i am not able to get my saved prefereces in the above code.
Please suggest a fix.

Comment: pull files from shared pref and u can watch the values too

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough context (specifically, the actual full code of `onCreate`) to determine the issue.

Comment: nothing more is there in onCreate. i m just calling few functions as specified.

Comment: Youv'e just messed up the variables 

's' and 'name'

for eg.

     s = prefs.getString("key", name);

You've got the value from shared preferences in the variable 's'. yet you pass

    i.putExtra("name", name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what `name` has when you do this :

```
if(name==null){
    setprefer();
}
else{
    getpref();
}
```

But since before checking you are not assigning any value to `name` variable, it's null and hence `setPrefer()` is called each time. You'll need to fetch the value from SharedPrefs and assign in to `name` before checking for `name == null`.

Answer (score 0):

Shared preference has a method called [contains](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)().Try that to check if shared preference already exists or not. That method will return true if the preference exists.

Comment: If you did that, and it was null, it would crash, with a NullPointerException.  So don't do that.  Also, 'matches' isn't great.  In both cases, use TextUtils.isEmpty(val), which handles both empty string and null.